# Javascript Scope and local variables

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

I'm really not sure if this is possible in Javascript. Here's my function:

```
var tree = function(name, callback) {
  if (this.name) {
    this.name.push(name)
    print(this.name)
  } else {
    this.name = []
  }
  callback()
}
```

I'd like to use it as follows and print out the hierarchy:

```
tree("john", function() {
  tree("geoff", function() {
    tree("peter", function() {
      tree("richard", function() {
      })
    })
  })
  tree("dave", function() {
  })
})
```

Here's the desired output:

```
// ['john']
// ['john', 'geoff']
// ['john', 'geoff', 'peter']
// ['john', 'geoff', 'peter', 'richard']
// ['john', 'dave']
```

but unfortunately I'm getting

```
// ['john', 'geoff', 'peter', 'richard', 'dave']
```

for the last function call. Is there a way to get the desired outcome?

Kind regards

Adam Groves

Comment: Are you trying to get the desired output by either not modifying the tree function or not modifying the way you are calling it?

Comment: Do you just care about the appearance of the printed output, or the resulting array structure?  Also, with the absense of a `new` operator, you know that `this` refers to `window`, yes?

Comment: I'd be happy to modify the tree function but would rather not alter the way it is called. Sorry for the delayed reply - I'm in Europe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the last line is printing all the names is because *this.names* is never removing the names that are being added to it. You're just appending names onto it. So when the function call is made

```
callback()
```

with the value

```
function() {
  tree("richard", function() {
})
```

*this.names = ['john', 'geoff', 'peter']* and after the call *this.names = ['john', 'geoff', 'peter', 'richard']*. So now when you call

```
tree("dave", function() {
});
```

this.names is still *['john', 'geoff', 'peter', 'richard']*.

Try the following instead, and notice I changed *this.name* to *this.names* to make is easier to read.

```
var tree = function(name, callback) {
  if (!this.names) {
    this.names = [];
  }
  this.names.push(name);
  print(this.names);
  callback();
  this.names.pop();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what callback does, but you should probably use apply() or call() when you invoke it.

```
callback.apply( this, arguments );
```

Comment: Callback is just the function 'tree' again being passed to itself.